# Need a formula to find year and quarter in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have this formula

```
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

-- This function takes a qtr (yyyyq), and adds the number of qtrs, and returns the future qtr
--e.g. FutureQtr (20154,7) returns 20173


CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FutureQtr_fn] (@StartQtr int,@AddlQtrs int)

Returns int

AS BEGIN

RETURN

      (@StartQtr/10*10)+ -- Current Year (yyyy)

            ((@StartQtr%(@StartQtr/10*10) +@AddlQtrs - 1)/4)*10 -- add'l years (n0)
            +(@StartQtr%(@StartQtr/10*10) +@AddlQtrs-1)%4  + 1 -- new qtr (n)

END
GO
```

I want to create a new formula called `dbo.GetPastQtr_fn` and I want it to produce the same result.

But instead of writing `select dbo.FutureQtr_fn (20154,7) -> 20173`
I want to write `dbo.GetPastQtr_fn (20154,7)` that will give me `20141`.

So it goes down!

Answer (score 0):

```
Select dbo.GetPastQtr_fn(20154,7)
```

Returns 20141

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetPastQtr_fn] (@StartQtr int,@AddlQtrs int)

Returns int

AS 

BEGIN
    Declare @Date Date=DateAdd(QQ,@AddlQtrs*-1,DateFromParts(@StartQtr/10,((@StartQtr-((@StartQtr/10)*10))*3),1))
    Return Year(@Date)*10+DatePart(QQ,@Date)
End
```